# Errores "Undefined index" ¿por qué está sucediendo?

Tags: php, php7

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

if ($_POST['contrasena1'] == $_POST['contrasena2']) {
     $rut = $_POST['rut'];
     $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
     $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $contraseña = md5($_POST['contrasena2']);
     $consulta = "INSERT INTO registros (rut, nombre, apellido, email, contraseña) VALUES ('$rut', '$nombre', '$apellido', '$email', '$contraseña')";
    
     $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die ("No se pudo crear el registro");
    
     header("Location:formulario.php?valida=si");
    
}else{
     header("location:formulario.php?errornea=si");
    }

?>
```

Conexion exitosa
Base de Datos encontrada

> Notice: Undefined index: contrasena1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\JP\sesion6_PHP\registro.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: contrasena2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\JP\sesion6_PHP\registro.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: rut in C:\xampp\htdocs\JP\sesion6_PHP\registro.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\JP\sesion6_PHP\registro.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: apellido in C:\xampp\htdocs\JP\sesion6_PHP\registro.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\JP\sesion6_PHP\registro.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: contrasena2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\JP\sesion6_PHP\registro.php on line 10

No se pudo crear el registro

Comment: Podrias colocar el html del formulario? porque lo que es claro que $_POST no tiene información de ningún formulario

Comment: Podrias colocar el html del formulario? porque lo que es claro que $_POST no tiene información de ningún formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que `$_POST` no tiene los indices a los cuales estás intentando acceder. Por indice me refiero a la clave con la cual quieres obtener el valor dentro de $_POST *(contrasena1, contrasena2, rut, etc)*

Ahora, no encuentra el valor por alguno de los siguientes motivos:

> 1) Los nombres de los inputs en tu formulario no corresponden a los nombres de las claves que quieres acceder.
>
> 2) Tu formulario tiene el metodo `GET` definido en vez de `POST`.

Si el problema es el primer caso, la solución es simplemente utilizar los mismos nombres. Por el contrario, si tu problema es el segundo, debes acceder a las propiedades mediante `$_GET` o `$_REQUEST` y no `$_POST`.

La solución es validar que exista la clave antes de acceder a ella, para ello puedes utilizar la función `isset()`.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['contrasena1']) && isset($_POST['contrasena2']) && isset($_POST['rut'])
   && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido']) && isset($_POST['email'])){

  if ($_POST['contrasena1'] == $_POST['contrasena2']) {
     $rut = $_POST['rut'];
     $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
     $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $contraseña = md5($_POST['contrasena2']);
     $consulta = "INSERT INTO registros (rut, nombre, apellido, email, contraseña) VALUES ('$rut', '$nombre', '$apellido', '$email', '$contraseña')";

     $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die ("No se pudo crear el registro");

     header("Location:formulario.php?valida=si");

}else{
     header("location:formulario.php?errornea=si");
    }
}else{
    echo "FALTAN DATOS PARA PROCESAR EL FORMULARIO";
}
```